# Cannot install keras-pandas on Ubuntu due to error message

Tags: python, ubuntu, keras, pip

I am able to download Keras through pip easily, but it didn't come with keras-pandas and when I run pip install -U keras-pandas I get the following error message:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-req-build-lw952foh/setup.py", line 12, in <module>
    with open('requirements.txt') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

I looked for the file, and didn't find anything, I've upgraded pip which didn't help, I just keep getting the same error code. How do I fix this bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug with the pandas-keras package.  I just submitted an issue:  https://github.com/bjherger/keras-pandas/issues/54

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in the keras-pandas, and is now fixed (as of version 1.3.3 and later).

See:  https://github.com/bjherger/keras-pandas/issues/54#issuecomment-416079727